# Loop over a directory and run easy_install on packages in a particular order

Tags: python, bash, jenkins

I am fairly new to bash scripting.

I have a bash script which must run offline (should work without internet). The script untars a xyz.tar.gz file and performs easy_install on a bunch of python packages which are .tar.gz files themselves. The 4 packages I am installing are:

```
multi_key_dict-2.0.3.tar.gz
pbr-1.10.0.tar.gz
python-jenkins-0.4.12.tar.gz
six-1.10.0.tar.gz
```

The problem is, six-1.10.0.tar.gz is a dependency for python-jenkins package. When I run the script, it tries to install these packages in alphabetical order; thus trying to install python-jenkins before six. Since there is no internet to get dependent packages, it fails. (Note that it is my requirement that I use easy_install over pip and the host machine should work offline)

How do I write the script in such a way that it installs rest of the 3 packages before it installs python-jenkins? I don't want to write 4 lines manually to install each package.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
for package in m* pb* s* py*; do
    easy_install "$package"
done
```

The above assumes that you are in a directory that contains those four files, and that `easy_install` requires a filename as first and only argument.

Basically the variable `package` will be assigned in this order:

```
multy_key_dict-2.0.3.tar.gz
pbr-1.10.0.tar.gz
six-1.10.0.tar.gz
python-jenkins-0.4.12.tar.gz
```

I hope you get the point of this `for` loop.

Comment: If its just 4 packages, I'd personally go with the unrolled version (Four `easy_install` commands in a sequence) -- Clean and readable.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan True, I would properly do the same. But I have no idea about how `easy_install` works, and OP explicit says: `I don't want to write 4 lines manually to install each package.`

Comment: Thanks @andlrc for your answer. Is there a way I can instruct my script to 'install this particular package last; for others order doesn't matter'?

Comment: @Alok Something like this might work: `for package in [^p]* p[^y]* py*;`